# charts disappear if rendered in hidden divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, hidden, chart.js

I have two charts (created with charts.js) that I want to alternate between on the click of a button.

Originally I had them each in separate divs with one hidden and one visible as follows:

```
<div id="one">
    <canvas id="myChart1" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
<div id="two" class="hidden">
    <canvas id="myChart2" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```

If I remove the 'hidden' class, the chart will not display.

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2rzkpzy9/12/

Is there any way around this or another way to approach alternating between them?

```js
var data1 = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        }]
};
var data2 = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "#FD6260",
            strokeColor: "#FD6260",
            pointColor: "#FD6260",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        }]
};

var options = {
    scaleShowGridLines : false,
    scaleShowHorizontalLines: false,
    scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
 }

var cxt = document.getElementById("myChart1").getContext("2d");
var chart = new Chart(cxt).Bar(data1,options);

var cxt2 = document.getElementById("myChart2").getContext("2d");
var chart2 = new Chart(cxt2).Bar(data2,options);
        
swap= function() {
     console.log(document.getElementById("one").className);
     document.getElementById("one").className = "hidden";
     document.getElementById("two").className = '';
    console.log(document.getElementById("one").className);
}
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://www.chartjs.org/assets/Chart.js"></script>
<div id="one">
    <canvas id="myChart1" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
<div id="two" class="hidden">
    <canvas id="myChart2" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn" onClick="swap()">Swap!</button>
<div id="info"></div>
```

Comment: two charts in the same shape ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't used Chart.js, but a quick glance at [the code](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/blob/master/Chart.js#L28) suggests that it's querying the DOM to get height and width for the render. If the containing div is hidden, that query probably returns `0`. So the hidden chart probably has 0x0 size. See https://jsfiddle.net/2rzkpzy9 for an example of this behavior:

```js
var width = document.getElementById('myChart').offsetWidth;

document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = width.toString();
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="hidden">
    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</div>

<div id="info"></div>
```

To fix, you might be able to set the width and height explicitly (not sure if Chart.js offers a config for this), or you can render the chart and *then* hide the element - not very elegant, since you might get a flash. Another version of the second option is to use something like `position: absolute; top: -1000px` to move the "hidden" div off-screen instead of hiding with `display: none`.

See your fiddle, updated to use the second option here: http://jsfiddle.net/2rzkpzy9/13/ - seems to work:

```js
var data1 = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        }]
};
var data2 = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "#FD6260",
            strokeColor: "#FD6260",
            pointColor: "#FD6260",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        }]
};

var options = {
    scaleShowGridLines : false,
    scaleShowHorizontalLines: false,
    scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
 }

var cxt = document.getElementById("myChart1").getContext("2d");
var chart = new Chart(cxt).Bar(data1,options);

var cxt2 = document.getElementById("myChart2").getContext("2d");
var chart2 = new Chart(cxt2).Bar(data2,options);
        
swap= function() {
     console.log(document.getElementById("one").className);
     document.getElementById("one").className = "hidden";
     document.getElementById("two").className = '';
    console.log(document.getElementById("one").className);
}
```

```css
.hidden {
    position: fixed;
    top: -1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://www.chartjs.org/assets/Chart.js"></script>
<div id="one">
    <canvas id="myChart1" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
<div id="two" class="hidden">
    <canvas id="myChart2" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn" onClick="swap()">Swap!</button>
<div id="info"></div>
```

Comment: Note that this swap only seems to work once; clicking again won't remove the coloration (I don't know if that was intentional or not).

Comment: I didn't dig into the code for the swap or anything - all I did was change the CSS spec for `.hidden`. Other implementation details left to the OP.

Comment: @TylerH Yeah I just simplified it for the jsfiddle. To make them switch on every click you would have to modify the swap function to either store and modify a state or check and see if 'hidden' was present in className or not.

Comment: This approach worked very well. Better than trying to `.update()` the chart. Use `.hidden`

Answer (score 5):

instead of hiding the inactive tab set its height to 0px and overflow:hidden

your css may look like this:

```
#one, #two
{
height:auto;
overflow:inherit;
}
#one.hidden, #two.hidden
{
height:0;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: This solution is the only one that worked for my case of wanting charts to render in tabs so they'd be included when cmd-p printing the page to PDF. Messing around with absolute positioning and `top: -10000px` stuff did not work for me on the present version of the lib, even when considering https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/responsive.html. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
swap= function() {
 console.log(document.getElementById("one").className);
 if(document.getElementById("one").className == "hidden"){
 document.getElementById("one").className = '';
 document.getElementById("two").className = 'hidden';
 }else{
 document.getElementById("one").className = 'hidden';
 document.getElementById("two").className = '';
 }

console.log(document.getElementById("one").className);
```

}

```js
var data1 = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        }]
};
var data2 = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "#FD6260",
            strokeColor: "#FD6260",
            pointColor: "#FD6260",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        }]
};

var options = {
    scaleShowGridLines : false,
    scaleShowHorizontalLines: false,
    scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
 }

var cxt = document.getElementById("myChart1").getContext("2d");
var chart = new Chart(cxt).Bar(data1,options);

var cxt2 = document.getElementById("myChart2").getContext("2d");
var chart2 = new Chart(cxt2).Bar(data2,options);
        
swap= function() {
     console.log(document.getElementById("one").className);
     if(document.getElementById("one").className == "hidden"){
     document.getElementById("one").className = '';
     document.getElementById("two").className = 'hidden';
     }else{
     document.getElementById("one").className = 'hidden';
     document.getElementById("two").className = '';
     }
     
    console.log(document.getElementById("one").className);
}
```

```css
.hidden {
    position: fixed;
    top: -1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.js"></script>
<div id="one">
    <canvas id="myChart1" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
<div id="two" class="hidden">
    <canvas id="myChart2" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn" onClick="swap()">Swap!</button>
<div id="info"></div>
```