# Chart.js not showing on second tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs, chart.js

I have two charts, one bar chart and one line chart that I'm creating. The bar chart is on tab one, while the line chart is in the second tab. The bar chart works fine, and if I point the line chart to tab 1 it works fine. The second tab is not rendering. I believe it is because the hidden container size is set to 0, and the chart is not being rendered when clicking on the second tab? I'm not sure how to correct this issue. Below are what I believe to be the relevant snippets of code:

HTML

```
<div class="" role="tabpanel" data-example-id="togglable-tabs">

<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs bar_tabs" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#tab_content1" id="bar-tab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true"> Bar Chart</a></li>
  <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="#tab_contentL" role="tab" id="Line-tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false"> Line Chart</a></li>
  <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="#tab_content2" role="tab" id="AMdata-tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false"> Auto/Manual Data</a></li>
  <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="#tab_content3" role="tab" id="FTPRdata-tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false"> FTPR Raw Data</a></li>
 </ul>

<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
 <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade active in" id="tab_content1" aria-labelledby="bar-tab">                         
  <canvas id="mybarChart2" height="350"></canvas>           
 </div>

 <div role="tabpaneL" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab_contentL" aria-labelledby="Line-tab">                         
  <canvas id="myLineChart" height="350"></canvas>           
 </div>
```

JS

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var cb = function(start, end, label) {
      console.log(start.toISOString(), end.toISOString(), label);
      $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    };

    var optionSet1 = {
      startDate: moment().startOf('month'),
      endDate: moment(),
      minDate: '01/01/2012',
      maxDate: '12/31/2020',
      /*dateLimit: {
        days: 60
      },*/
      showDropdowns: true,
      showWeekNumbers: true,
      timePicker: false,
      timePickerIncrement: 1,
      timePicker12Hour: true,
      ranges: {
        'Today': [moment(), moment()],
        'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
        //'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
        //'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
        'Month to Date': [moment().startOf('month'), moment()],
        //'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')],
        'Quarter to Date': [moment().startOf('quarter'), moment()],            
        'Year to Date': [moment().startOf('year'), moment()]
      },
      opens: 'left',
      buttonClasses: ['btn btn-default'],
      applyClass: 'btn-small btn-primary',
      cancelClass: 'btn-small',
      format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
      separator: ' to ',
      locale: {
        applyLabel: 'Submit',
        cancelLabel: 'Clear',
        fromLabel: 'From',
        toLabel: 'To',
        customRangeLabel: 'Custom',
        daysOfWeek: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
        monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
        firstDay: 1
      }
    };
    $('#reportrange span').html(moment().startOf('month').format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + moment().format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker(optionSet1, cb);
    $('#reportrange').on('show.daterangepicker', function() {
      console.log("show event fired");
    });
    $('#reportrange').on('hide.daterangepicker', function() {
      console.log("hide event fired");
    });
    $('#reportrange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
      console.log("apply event fired, start/end dates are " + picker.startDate.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + " to " + picker.endDate.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    });
    $('#reportrange').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
      console.log("cancel event fired");
    });
    $('#options1').click(function() {
      $('#reportrange').data('daterangepicker').setOptions(optionSet1, cb);
    });
    $('#options2').click(function() {
      $('#reportrange').data('daterangepicker').setOptions(optionSet2, cb);
    });
    $('#destroy').click(function() {
      $('#reportrange').data('daterangepicker').remove();
    });

    $('#reportrange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
      //console.log(picker.startDate.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
      //dont need to do any changing of props here.
  //starting = picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
  console.log("Data changed. Reloading data...");
  myDataTable.ajax.reload();
  myDataTableFTPR.ajax.reload();
  myDataTableFTPRLoc.ajax.reload();
  loadFTPRChart(picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'),picker.endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
  loadFTPRLine(picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'),picker.endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
    });



Chart.defaults.global.maintainAspectRatio = false;

/*update chart instead of destroy and recreate */

// define a variable to store the chart instance (this must be outside of your function)
var myChart;

function loadFTPRChart(startdate, enddate) {
var BCData = {
labels: [],
datasets: [{
  label: "Pass %",
  backgroundColor: "rgba(83,106,127,1)",
  data: [],
  stack: 1
}, {
  label: "Fail %",
  backgroundColor: "rgba(83,106,127,.2)",
  data: [],
  stack: 1
}, {
  label: "Auto %",
  backgroundColor: "rgba(40,96,144,1)",
  data: [],
  stack: 2
}, {
  label: "Manual %",
  backgroundColor: "rgba(40,96,144,.2)",
  data: [],
  stack: 2
}]
};

$.getJSON("content/FTPR_AM_Graph_ajax.php", {
  startdate: startdate,
  enddate: enddate,
  location: "M"
})
.done(function(data) {
  console.log("data", data);
  $.each(data.aaData, function(key, val) {
    if (val == "") {
      return true
    }
    BCData.labels.push("Coater " + val[0]);
    BCData.datasets[0].data.push(parseFloat(val[2]));
    BCData.datasets[1].data.push(parseFloat(100 - val[2]));
    BCData.datasets[2].data.push(parseFloat(val[1]));
    BCData.datasets[3].data.push(parseFloat(100 - val[1]));
  });

  var option = {
    responsive: true,
  };
  console.log("BCData", BCData);

  // if the chart is not undefined (e.g. it has been created)
  // then just update the underlying labels and data for each
  // dataset and re-render the chart
  if (myChart) {
    myChart.data.labels = BCData.labels;
    myChart.data.datasets[0].data = BCData.datasets[0].data;
    myChart.data.datasets[1].data = BCData.datasets[1].data;
    myChart.data.datasets[2].data = BCData.datasets[2].data;
    myChart.data.datasets[3].data = BCData.datasets[3].data;
    myChart.update();
  } else {
    // otherwise, this is the first time we are loading so create the chart
    var ctx = document.getElementById("mybarChart2").getContext("2d");
    myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: BCData,
      options: {
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              max: 100,
            },
            stacked: true,
          }]
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
}

loadFTPRChart($('#reportrange').data().daterangepicker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'), $('#reportrange').data().daterangepicker.endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));    


var myLine;

function loadFTPRLine(startdate, enddate) {
var LCData = {
labels: [],
datasets: [{
  label: "FTPR Weekly",
  borderColor: "rgba(83,106,127,1)",
  data: [],
  stack: 1,
  fill: false,
  lineTension: .25,      
}]
};

$.getJSON("content/FTPRLine_ajax.php", {
  location: "M",
  startdate: startdate,
  enddate: enddate
})

.done(function(data) {
  console.log("data", data);
  $.each(data.aaData, function(key, val) {
    if (val == "") {
      return true
    }
    LCData.labels.push(val[0]);
    LCData.datasets[0].data.push(parseFloat(val[1]));        
  });

  var option = {
    responsive: true,
  };
  console.log("LCData", LCData);

  // if the chart is not undefined (e.g. it has been created)
  // then just update the underlying labels and data for each
  // dataset and re-render the chart
  if (myLine) {
    myLine.data.labels = LCData.labels;
    myLine.data.datasets[0].data = LCData.datasets[0].data;
    myLine.update();
  } else {
    // otherwise, this is the first time we are loading so create the chart
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myLineChart").getContext("2d");
    myLine = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: LCData,
      options: {
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{               
            stacked: false,
            ticks: {
              suggestedMin: 0
            }
          }],
          xAxes: [{             
            ticks: {
                autoSkip: true,
                maxTicksLimit: 20
              }
          }]
        }
      }
    });
  }
});

}

loadFTPRLine($('#reportrange').data().daterangepicker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'), $('#reportrange').data().daterangepicker.endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
```

So the first section of JS is my daterangepicker. The second is the bar chart and the third is the line chart. I know that it's creating them correctly, because if I make the line chart the "active" tab then it works fine, same with the bar chart. How do I go about getting them to both work?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: You will have to draw the line chart in a callback for the 'shown.bs.tab' event, as defined here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-events

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you suspect is happening is correct.  There are 2 options to fix this (note...option 2 is the easiest).

1) Use the `shown.bs.tab` event callback to either create your other chart, or if you created earlier in your javascript you can just call it's `.update()` function.

```
$('a[href="#pie"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(){
  myPie.update();
});
```

2) Put your `<canvas>` element inside a `<div>` within your tab.  With this approach you don't have to use the tab events at all.  Here is an [example](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/zZpxZv) demonstrating this.

Comment: Hi Jordan, thank you for the help! I am trying out your second option right now. It looks like it works correctly except for one problem - it only works if I take out this section of code: 

Chart.defaults.global.maintainAspectRatio = false;

When I take this out, the sizing of the charts are all messed up (much larger since I want the width to be 100%). Any idea why this is? When I set the height to 350px the formatting messes up (can no longer read any of the labels).

Comment: Are you saying that the tabs don't work unless you set maintainAspectRatio = false?

Comment: Sometimes, `.update()` does not works. So, you can use another approach, described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31729518/11296031

Answer (score 4):

I use `maintainAspectRatio: false` and I fixed this issue by applying a note on chartjs documentation. Put the canvas into div container with style dimension attributes.

```
<div class="chart-container" style="position: relative; height:40vh; width:80vw">
     <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The marked answer did not work for me since I use `maintainAspectRatio: false` to fill the full height of the screen. I was able to get it working by doing the following:

```
var currentWindowHeight = $(window).height()
var chartHeight = currentWindowHeight - 220

$("#my-tab").on("shown.bs.tab", function(){
    $("#mycanvasid").css("height", chartHeight);
});
```